# Yet another condition for a map to be completely-positive and trace-preserving

Tags: quantum-operation, decoherence

Surely, these conditions are all well-defined and well-known (via the Choi, Kraus, and Stinespring presentations). Is the following 'definition' valid? Does it make sense?

"The map is CPTP if, when expressed as a matrix acting on a vectorized density operator -*in an arbitrary basis* - and then subjected to the superdecoherence  (i.e., in the corresponding Choi state all the off-diagonal elements are washed out) yields a stochastic matrix"

Comment: Can you maybe define more precisely what you mean by superdecoherence? Where did you get this definition? For it to be a "valid" definition you need to prove that it holds iff one of the other conditions hold.

Comment: "Superdecoherence" is the following procedure: You transform the map into the corresponding Choi state. Then the Choi state is written down in some bi-basis. Finally, all elements of this Chou matrix are nullified - except the diagonal one. Last step: reshuffle the obtained  diagonal state into a map. The resulting map will be a stochastic matrix plus a set of decoupled exponentially decaying modes.

Comment: so you're saying to put to zero all off-diagonal elements of the Choi, and obtain a "stochastic matrix", which for a diagonal matrix means to equal the identity? That doesn't seem right. You'd be saying that the Choi needs to have 1 on the diagonal, which is not true

Comment: @glS I am saying the following: If you decohere the Choi state, i.e. 'put to zero all off-diagonal elements' (in any basis) and then reshuffle the so obtained diagonal Choi it into a map - you end up with a classical stochastic matrix 'coated' with N^2-N decoupled modes

Comment: so in practice you're just saying: a map is a channel iff its Choi is positive semidefinite, ok. But only if you're saying you get a positive semidefinite diagonal matrix after decoherence in all possible bases (which maybe is what you meant, but it wasn't entirely clear to me)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is indeed 'yes' because it is a tautology: Just another way to say that the Choi state is non-negative and the original map is trace preserving. So, it is a CPTP map.

To unfold: A state, i. e., a density operator, is a positive semidefinite operator. It means that if  it is expressed in  the form of a density matrix - in *any* basis - the matrix diagonal consists of non-negative elements only (additionally normalized so they are probabilities but this is not important in the current context).  Next, a map is completely positive iff its Choi operator is  positive-semidefinite.

Another words, the Choi operator, when expressed in any bi-basis, has non-negative diagonal elements. Superdecoherence (which is basis specific) washes out all of-diagonal elements of the Choi matrix and keeps only diagonal elements.  Note that this 'washed-out' Choi matrix still represents a state --  it is still positive-semidefinite. Now this Choi matrix is reshuffled into a map. This map is a stochastic matrix 'coated' with $N-1$ decoupled exponentially decaying - and $N$-time degenerated -  modes. Therefore, for a CPTP map, superdecoherence will always result in a stochastic matrix - for *any* basis - simply becuase the corresponding Choi operator is a state (semidefinite positive).

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @FDGod  Yes, sure. See above.